# Discord bot that automatically add emojis only to links

Tags: python, hyperlink, discord, bots

Apologies for my English.

I'm trying to create a Discord Bot that automatically reacts with emojis only, if we send a link (youtube link). If we don't send links, the bot doesn't have to react.
This is what I have tried :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?')

@bot.event                                                                      #Message when the bot is ready
async def on_ready():
    print ("Wsh frr chuis prêt !")

async def react(message):                                                       #Emojis that have to be added only if the msg starts with "https://" or "http://"
    if (message.startswith("https://")) or (message.startswith("http://")):
        custom_emojis = [
        "<:Kaneki:734573154831433748>"
        ]
        guild_emoji_names = [str(guild_emoji) for guild_emoji in message.guild.emojis]
        for emoji in custom_emojis:
            #print(emoji, guild_emoji_names)
            #print(emoji in guild_emoji_names)
            if emoji in guild_emoji_names:
                await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 734184787241074758:                                #Channel where messages have to be in to work
            await react(message)

bot.run('<Some_token>')          #Bot's token
```

I think that the problem is at the 13th line. I tried to use `message.startswith()` but there's an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

If you could help me, it would be cool ! Thanks :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the tool that you are using, but the issue you are experiencing is because `message` is an instance of `Message` and it does not implement the method `startswith`. I believe that you are confusing that with a string. Maybe you should look in the documentation for the property/attribute/method that gets you the string that you are expecting so you use that verification.

Comment: Okay so I replaced 
`async def react(message):` and `if (message.startswith("https://")) or (message.startswith("http://")):`, by :`prefix = "?"` `async def react(message):` `if prefix + str(message):` `custom_emojis = [`
But the new problem is that even if we don't put the "?" at the beggining of our msg, the bot will still react with his emojis.. any help please?

Comment: I finally finished my programe lol, ive just replaced `prefix = "?"` by `if "?" in lien.content.lower():` and it works, thanks for your help and your time ;)